# Handling rare levels in a categorical variable? (or maybe it's not categorical at all)

Tags: correlation, predictive-models, modeling, categorical-encoding, many-categories

I have a dataset where I'm trying to predict completion time of an application. There are a number of numeric and categorical predictors, with a one group of predictors being holds. An application may have multiple types of holds placed on it, and each hold may be placed multiple times. I'm not quite sure how to handle these variables. I figure I will make each type of hold its own category and count the number of instances per application.

But there are 60+ types of holds. I would like to throw out (or combine) the rare ones to make the modeling a bit easier. However I'm not sure how to identify what the rare holds are. In a set of 100K applications, at the bottom end one hold type is only placed 5 times across all applications, while another is placed 150K times. The median is 1000. How do I identify rare holds when the distribution is so skewed? Also some of the holds may interact with one another.

Or am I thinking about this entirely the wrong way and I should be treating each hold like a numerical variable?

I'm wary about using something like PCA because I would like to be able to identify the most important individual variables at the end.

Comment: A "hold" is some condition causing the application to wait. And the same hold can be applied anew, after it has been raised? So for each hold, you are counting the number of times it has been applied? This means that the values of the predictor variables, will be changing under the application process. If your dataset contains applications finally approved, with the total processing time used as response variable, how do you intent to apply this model for prediction for new cases, when the values of the predictor variables will be unknown/changing?

Comment: It's a good question--application prediction time would be used as a snapshot prediction using the latest pulled data, with the understanding that yes, it might change.